# Cannot browse using OpenVPN in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, openvpn

On Ubuntu 13.10 Private Internet Access worked great but since changing to Kubuntu 14.04 when I press  connect from the network manager it connect but there is no Internet access? I also imported the ovpn files and entered the correct username/password.

Comment: Sounds like a redirect-gateway statement is missing in the OpenVPN configuration (or it isn't pushed/pulled by the client). You may want to untick "Use only for resources on this connection" in the IPv4 routes dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the openvpn daemon manually in your terminal by entering

```
> sudo service openvpn start
```

This worked for me, but I have no idea why network-manager doesn't start this service automatically since it is necessary for openvpn-connections.

EDIT: i managed to connect to the vpn with actual internet access by disabling the "Use TAP-Device"-checkbox in the advanced-dialog. Maybe this helps someone else, who stumbles upon this problem.
credits to: ["Linuxwelt - Muhamed H."](http://linuxwelt.blogspot.de/2013/12/cyberghost-vpn-verbindung-unter-linux.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with ubuntu 14.04.
Connecting with openvpn using gnome network manager. In the system log I found:

"Error: Connection activation failed: no valid VPN secrets."

To fix your connection open your config file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/YourConnectionName
```

Set the password flag to zero:

```
password-flags=0
```

And add the following lines:

```
[vpn-secrets]
password=YourPassword
```